# Refreshing pages with java script calling

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, webview

I have some webView's , and one viewController that set small `webView` and display pages by calling to java script with diffrent values.

I am using the next code to call and display the result:

```
 NSString * js = [NSString myScript:@"%@('%@');",@"showPageById", idNumber];
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
        [self.viewController.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Every time i send `idNUmber` i should get diffrent page, but the problem is  after i sending once to java script `idNumber` i'm displaying the new page, but after calling it again with new `idNUmber` i'm getting always the same **previous page**! if i start again, so also only the first one is displayed.

I tried `reload` but its not working...

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you sure that isNumber is getting changed in between calls? Check to see also that your script handles the different idNumbers correctly. Try placing your javascript in a file and run it in your normal browser and running it and see what you get in between calls. Also check where you are calling the function from.

Comment: By the logs the idNumber is changing for 100%, also when i run it on browser it works as it supposed to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I made a simple view controller which adds the UIWebView manually to itself like you were trying to do. Also its a private UIWebView. I created a simple button which passes an `alert()` to the UIWebView and it works every time, so here is the whole code so you can see whats going on.

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SOFViewController : UIViewController
// This is linked as action thru nib.
- (IBAction)hitMe:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

**.m file**

Here please note the placement of where I first call the javascript into the webView which is in `ViewDidAppear`, other preceding functions will cause bad behaviour when first launching in simulator. I am using Xcode 4.3

```
#import "SOFViewController.h"

@interface SOFViewController ()
{
    int idNumber;
    UIWebView *webViewMain;
}

@end

@implementation SOFViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webViewMain = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:webViewMain];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    idNumber = idNumber + 1;
    NSString * js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%d');",idNumber];

    [webViewMain stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)hitMe:(UIButton *)sender {
    idNumber = idNumber + 1;
    NSString * js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('%d');",idNumber];
    [webViewMain stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
@end
```

Hope this has some how helped.